# On danger of being tedious,

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm not entirely sure if this expression exists:

> *On danger of being tedious*, we are still waiting for the update that you promised many times.

... where *being tedious* could be replaced with e.g. *repeating myself* or *being annoying*.

If not, how would I express that I am (politely) sorry for the repetition in asking, but I need and rightfully expect something to be done?

Comment: I think the principal problem is "On danger of..." which is certainly not known in BrE. Or is that the bit you're asking about?

Comment: I thought I saw this specific expression (on danger of) being used, but I was later unable to find it anywhere. Most likely I just misremembered and got confused about the correct expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try "at the risk of being tedious"

> **at the risk of (doing something)** idiom
>
> : despite the possibility of (doing something that could be considered improper, wrong, etc.)
> //*At the risk of* sounding rude, I have to ask you how old you are.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20the%20risk%20of%20(doing%20something)

Like *Merriam-Webster* suggests, it may be more common to phrase your sentence as: "At the risk of being tedious, *I have to mention that* we are still waiting for the update that you promised many times."  But really, it's a common enough phrase that you could leave out the "I have to mention" and still be easily understood.

---

The first thing that popped into my head was a Paul Simon lyric:

> But I'll repeat myself, at the risk of being rude
> There must be 50 ways to leave your lover

Answer (score 0):

As in:

> On danger of being a pest, we are still waiting for the update that
>   you promised many times.

pest   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pest)

> An annoying person or thing; a nuisance.

An unwanted, bothersome person is a pest — and so is an unwanted, bothersome bug. In fact, the "destructive or harmful insect" definition came before "annoying person," following the "plague or pestilence" meaning of pest.